# How to return non 200 HTTP status codes with Serverless + OpenWhisk and behind IBM Cloud API Gateway?

Tags: openwhisk

I can't figure out how to return http status codes for functions behind an API GW. No matter what I return, it always comes back as a 200. I've tried `statusCode` and `code` to no avail.

I'm using the Serverless framework with the OpenWhisk plugin. I'm deploying to IBM Cloud.

Comment: your function must return a formatted response like this `{
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: {}
    }`
can you share your code? these docs may be helpful https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/webactions.md

Comment: statusCode should do the trick, check the doc that @user6062970 shared for webactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Action response content type parameter must be set to `http` to manually [configure the HTTP response](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/apigateway.md#full-control-over-the-http-response). This value defaults to `json` which ignores returned `headers` and `statusCode` values.

In The Serverless Framework, this value is set in the [event configuration section](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-openwhisk#connecting-http-endpoints) of your YAML.

```
functions:
  my_function:
    handler: index.main
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /api/greeting
          resp: http
```